# Is this beacon the tail end of a 'Numbers Station' broadcast?

Tags: signal-identification, beacon, swl

I was recently scanning through the short-wave frequencies and stumbled upon a series of repeating tones, which then cut to classical music and then a woman speaking French (unconfirmed). Later I was unable to locate anything but static on that frequency.

I recorded the brief moment on my phone and the **recording can be listened to [here](https://soundcloud.com/shortsurrey/11970khz-13092014-2059) (SoundCloud).**

I am aware that numbers stations exist and are known to start with repeating tones, [The Lincolnshire Poacher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincolnshire_Poacher_(numbers_station)) is known for this - though this beacon seemed to be ending on one, not beginning.

Am I just confusing a commercial station's opening signals for something more? The UK Shipping Forecast is always lead into by a musical score for people to listen for when tuning in and perhaps this is just a similar method.

What is frustrating is that the tones played in the beacon are somewhat recognisable but I cannot place where they are from.

---

## **Details:**

**Frequency:** 11970khz

**Date & Time:** 13/09/2014 - 20:59 (DD/MM/YYYY - HH-MM)

Answer (score 4):

After catching it again today, at 19:30 BST on 5.90mhz I looked it up on [shortwaveschedule](http://www.shortwaveschedule.com/). It seems to be the lead-in call for Radio Romania International.

Mystery solved.

The introductory music & beacon can also be heard on [this old recorded broadcast from 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVMGnMT5FXU).